# logs between two dates i unix

Tags: shell, unix, logging

I am trying to fetch the logs between two specific dates from a big log fine.

My log format is

```
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFactory.createSubject(71) | HTTP Session id: B37D367C02B5411489152F5EF4D740B3
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,226]  EfmsWebSubjectFactory.createSubject(79) | Subject Context is associated to principal: None
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,226]  EfmsWebSubjectFactory.createSubject(85) | Created new subject instance for user null
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,228]  LoginController.login(53) | Login page requested
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:42,636]  EfmsWebSubjectFactory.createSubject(71) | HTTP Session id: B37D367C02B5411489152F5EF4D740B3
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:42,636]  EfmsWebSubjectFactory.createSubject(79) | Subject Context is associated to principal: None
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:42,636]  EfmsWebSubjectFactory.createSubject(85) | Created new subject instance for user null
```

and I am trying in this way

> sed -n '/[EFMS]  DEBUG [06 Apr 2014 00:00:00/,/[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 00:00:00/p' catalina.logs

and it is not working, could you please help me with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `sed`, you need `grep`. Besides that, your query is too overcomplicated, if you need event that happened on 6th, you can only search for 6th:

```
grep "06 Apr 2014" catalina.logs
```

If you need to specify wider amount of days, you may use a regular expression to do that, e.g.:

```
grep "[1-3][0-9] Mar 2014" catalina.logs
```

will search for all entries from March.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be an easy way to parse the timestamp without converting them to epoch seconds and finding a range. If you are just looking for entire day time, you can do:

```
sed -n '/06 Apr 2014/,/07 Apr 2014/p' catalina.logs
```

You need to escape the meta-characters like `[` and `]`. Also putting the entire timestamp might not work if they don't exist in your logs.

Comment: Sorry, taking that back, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want arbitrary date ranges, you can do it with the following `awk` script:

```
{
    mm = (index ("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", $4) + 2) / 3;
    if (mm < 10) { mm = "0"mm; };

    dd = $3;
    gsub (/\[/, "", dd);

    date = $5"-"mm"-"dd;

    if ((date >= from) && (date <= to)) { print; };
}
```

It works by converting the date into the correct format for comparison (`yyyy-mm-dd`), and only printing out the lines between the dates given on the command line.

A transcript follows in which you can see only the dates between `from` and `to` are included (first and last line deleted since they fall outside the range desired):

```
pax> cat input.txt
[EFMS]  DEBUG [05 Feb 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [06 Mar 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,226]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,226]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,228]  LoginController.l...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:42,636]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:42,636]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:42,636]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 May 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Aug 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...

pax> awk -vfrom=2014-03-01 -vto=2014-05-08 -f filter.awk input.txt
[EFMS]  DEBUG [06 Mar 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,226]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,226]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:35,228]  LoginController.l...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:42,636]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:42,636]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 Apr 2014 11:07:42,636]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
[EFMS]  DEBUG [07 May 2014 11:07:35,225]  EfmsWebSubjectFac...
```